# Crap screwdrivers packaged with self assembly furniture

Tags: tools

[image: Disposable Screwdriver]

What is the "official" name for these and where might I be able to buy more?

Apologies if this is off topic, but figured the people here would know what I am talking about.

Edit: Sorry, let me clarify.  I know its a Philips screwdriver.  I am more focused on the cheapness.  It is borderline disposable.  Can these be purchased in bulk somewhere?

Comment: If you’ve already figured out that they’re crap, why would you want a lot of them? Is this for commercial purposes?

Comment: you can buy those with a couple of tabs for opening beer bottles

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate sometimes its nice to be able to stash tools where they're needed. If you have something that's a cross head, and needs tightening periodically, sticking them on a keyring and hanging it nearby would be a positive thing

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The handle on my Wok fits that description, I keep a Swiss Army Knife in my cutlery drawer (also useful for the rare bottles of wines that still come with a cork).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately - there's probably no standard name for it, and chinese manufacturers tend to keyword stuff. I *did* find a supplier on [alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Crosshead-screwdriver-wrench-furniture-hardware-tool_1600094488076.html) that'd sell you as many as you want for 5 cents and shipping and they call it a *takes a deep breath* "Crosshead screwdriver wrench furniture hardware tool parts simple triangle cross spanner"

That said, you can often *find* what something is using google lens - I uploaded a photo of the question with the wrench, ignored google bringing up the same question and that brought up some options

[image]

While it needs some digging, I'm a fan of teaching people to fish, and it  might be useful for future users, or tool searches if you know what you want, and not what its called.

Answer (score 1):

Philips.  I would guess the size as #2 or #3.

Any store with a hardware section will have very many types from just bits to full size kits in almost every handle design.

I doubt most stores will carry that exact design, because of the reason you gave.

The size of the end is the important part to match the screw head.  The shaft and handle is not important.

Answer (score 1):

That would be equivalent to a stubby Phillips screwdriver, probably a #2 or #3  similar to the one shown below from ACE hardware. Whether the shortness or stubbyness is needed or not depends on the furniture you're assembling.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Can these be purchased in bulk somewhere?"

Yes they can. From whom is the difficult question.

There are 3 possibilities;

1-Try looking for information on the container of the furniture you purchased. There may be information that can direct you to a company that actually produces  the product. This is probably in China, so communicating may be difficult.

2-The other possibility is to contact an importing agent. They will look for the product for you.

3-A final possibility is contacting a manufacturing facility to ask if they will make them for you.  The problem is they will want you to pay for any tooling necessary. So this can be expensive to start.  Maybe go back to #2.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a Phillips-head screwdriver. They are sold everywhere. What makes a good screwdriver is the hardened tip. Most cheap screwdrivers will cam out and wear quickly. If this is your first screwdriver, you can't go wrong with something [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001HSNHM2).

[image]

Comment: Wera makes lifetime-grade stuff, which is nice but is also reflected in the price. I think you can get a decent quality screwdriver set for less.